# Determine how a Windows service was started

Tags: windows, service

I have a Windows service that with Start Type = Automatic, so that the service starts on boot.  If the user stops my service explicitly and restarts it (or some other component of my product stops my service explicitly and restarts it), I need to know that and behave differently in the service.

Is there an API to detect "this service was started automatically by Windows on boot" vs "this service was started manually"?  I can't find one on MSDN.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try setting command-line arguments for the service (see the description of lpBinaryPathName in CreateService or ChangeServiceConfig).  I'm not certain, but I believe these arguments are only passed to the executable when the service is automatically started.

Comment: Thanks Harry Johnston.  My own recollection was that if you put arguments in lpBinaryPathName, they'd also be passed on a normal 'sc start' or 'net start'.  I haven't tried it though.  We eventually hacked around the whole problem by passing arguments to StartService if the service was started programmatically but manually.